# Handle errors to file in Workflow

Tags: powershell, workflow, parallel.foreach

I have PowerShell script with a workflow and `foreach -parallel`. I set `TimeoutSec` inside the workflow for an `InlineScript` block.

When I set sleep command to 15 sec, I got error below:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The activity has exceeded the
specified maximum running time of 10 seconds.
At create-new-vms:25 char:25
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], TimeoutException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TimeoutException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

I want write this error to log files (one file per error for every `foreach` element). How to do this? What must I add to my script?

My script:

```
$newvmlist = "test1", "test2"

workflow create-new-vms {
  param(
    [string[]]$vms
  )

  foreach -parallel ($vm in $vms) {
    $run = InlineScript {
      # Create New VM
      echo " "
      echo " "
      echo "___"
      echo "VM Name - $Using:vm " 
      echo "----"
      echo " "
      echo " "
      sleep 15
    } -PSActionRunningTimeoutSec 10 

    $run
  }
}

create-new-vms -vms $newvmlist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ErrorVariable`:

```
create-new-vms -vms $newvmlist -ErrorVariable err
$err |% {$i=0}{ $i++; $_ | out-file "$i.log" }
```